# Automation of system panels on OSX, to load or save files

Tags: macos, selenium, automation

How do I automate OSX system panels?

I would like to load and save files, and I did try with Selenium but when the system panel appear, I can't access these.
From my application I can send keystroke; which result in opening the system dialog to pick a file; but then I can't go on.

I believe that Selenium is good only for Web automation; since it does not support anything system-side, like application bar or load/save panels.

Answer (score 0):

No, selenium does not support system dialogs.
You can try sendKeys to the element if it is input element.

if not, you can build script by sikuli or other third part software like the
suggested in this link:
http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=mac

Comment: Thanks Hezi; could you please elaborate on the "sendKeys" part? I do simulate the shortcut that open the file dialog; to load a file, but any other keyboard command that I pass is not accepted, as long as the file dialog is up

Comment: you don't need to click and open the dialog. assume that the input element looks like this: <input id = 'bla' type ='file' /> you should take the element and send key to it like this: driver.findElement(By.id('bla')).sendKeys("Path to file");